# Send data to controller via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, web

I am new to Ajax and I am using laravel, now i want to have a delete button that will send the id of the item that i want to delete to controller. Here is my code.

Views

```
      <div class="row">
        @foreach($photos as $photo)
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
    <button onclick="removeItem({{$photo->id}}); return false;">Delete</button>   
          </div> 
          @endforeach

        </div>
```

Here is my script for now, doesnt have an idea on this

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeItem($myvar) {
        alert($myvar);
    }
    </script>
```

I want to send this to this route

```
       Route::post('deletephoto','GamefarmsController@deletephoto');
```

Comment: Have a look at jquery's [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function and use use laravel's `Request::ajax()` if appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an XMLHTTPRequest to the server via AJAX. Since you are using a jQuery as javascript library, such request is easy using functions like [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

your HTML/template:

```
<button class="my_button" id="{{$photo->id}}" data-url="{{path('deletephoto')}}">Delete</button>
```

So, inside your javascript function, use something like:

```
function removeItem() {

     $('button.my_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();     
            var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: {id:id},
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){

                            }
                            });

        return false;
       });

    }
```

In details:
We add a data attribute to your HTML button that would contain your path, If you are using Twig as templating engine, you can write something like:

```
data-url={{path('path_delete')}}
```

But it depends on your template engine and laravel way of routing.

Then using the attr() jQuery function onclick on your button:

```
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
```

You can apply the same rule to get your id.

Finally, you should write a controller that will get the POST request with the id parameter and perform deletion. You can get your id from the request object inside controller, something like:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
      {
$id = (int)$request->request->get('id');

}
```

Comment: Help again sir, I just dont understand this part - data-url={{path('path_delete')}}

Comment: This is a data attribute that you can add to your html (your button). You can then retrieve its value using jQuery. `{{path('path_delete')}}` is not exactly what you should put because it depends on your templating engine. Me I used twig for your example. The main idea is to return the target url in your HTML button as an attribute to fetch it using javascript jquery and then use it as the url in your ajax call.

Comment: I really dont understand sir, Can you edit your answer and use my given data. Thank you so much Sir, I really need help

Comment: First! try to return in your html the target url (url related to  `Route::post('deletephoto','GamefarmsController@deletephoto');) `. Then, create a jQuery listener that will listen to button click (instead of making inline javascript, give your button a class name). I honnesly suggest you spend some time doing a homework, this task is really interesting for your resume.

Comment: I gave additionnaly an edit to help you, but as I said, this is an important part of web development that you should give time learning

Comment: one more thing sir, how can you get this -  var id = your_id; since i am looping the result to get the ids

Comment: with the same approach . create a data attribute for id. each of your loop-generated buttons will contain its id in  `id` attribute.. look at edit.

Comment: it is not listening to the click event, nothings happening when clicked

Comment: btw i am using blade, so this code data-url={{path('path_delete')}} will be like this ?data-url={{route('path_delete')}}

Comment: Its working now, but I just dont know if I made the proper route, I just can test if its working, i did a die and dump but nothings happening

Comment: I am following your advancement. Just keep digging about this task, it is very interesting for your learning . Hint :"read about routing component in laravel and  Blade related functions"

Comment: i tried to view the console and I found this error sir HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What is the exact error? it is a 500 but which one?

Comment: I think it can reach the routes, the problem is reaching the controller